# Mysql Complex SELECT

Tags: mysql

I've three table 'Hardware_model','Warehouse' and 'Brand' and tables are refernced together in this way:
Hardware_model <-> Warehouse
Hardware_model <-> Brand

Now I want execute the following query: select all 'warehouse' object that has a 'brand_id equal to '10'). Off course warehouse and brand are not joined so no foreign keys exists between them. I was trying something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM warehouses 
where hardware_id = (SELECT * 
                    FROM hardwares 
                    where brand_id='10')
```

but it doesn't works!
where hardware_id is a 'warehouse table' field and brand_id is a 'hardware table' field.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a simple multi-table join. You just need to do something along the lines of (I can only guess the table structure).

```
SELECT w.* FROM warehouses w
JOIN hardwares h ON w.hardware_id = h.hardware_id
JOIN brands b ON h.brand_id = b.brand_id
WHERE brand_id=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your subquery returns more than one column, and possibly more than one row. You should be able to do this with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM warehouses
JOIN hardwares ON warehouses.hardware_id = hardwares.id
WHERE brand_id = '10'
```

`hardwares.id` should be replaced with whatever key `warehouses.hardware_id` references. Even if you haven't specified a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, you can still join tables.

Answer (score 0):

Surpriased that doesn't fall over in a  big heap should be something like

```
SELECT *  FROM warehouses  
where hardware_id in (SELECT hardware_id FROM hardwares where brand_id='10')
```

Comment: MySQL can't optimize sub-selects like this well so a `JOIN` stands much more of a chance of running optimally. I think you meant `hardware_id IN(SELECT...` too

Comment: Right about in, and amended accordingly. I'd prefer a join myself but I wanted to point of  in select * from was never working...

Answer (score 0):

just guessing at your tables, but maybe

```
SELECT w1.*  
FROM warehouses w1,
     hardware   h1
 where w1.hardware_id = h1.hardware_id
 and h1.brand_id=10
```

Do you have a hardware_id in your warehouse table? if not, where are you making the relation between your warehouse and what is in it?

Comment: yeah,I've as I've already stated hardware_id is in my warehouse table